# Cómo funciona el método sort con function(a,b){return a-b;} como argumento

Tags: javascript

En este código la parte que **NO entiendo** es como la función anónima recibe los argumentos, creo que es un `callback`, el `array` envia los elementos **al método** `sort`, luego este los envía a la `función anónima`, y luego resta los argumentos, pero no entiendo nada de esa parte, osea:

1) Se supone que son `strings`, como los suma, los convierte a **numero primeramente**?

2) Suponiendo que tendríamos un `array` **con dos elementos** `"25"` y `"100"` (*en ese orden*),la función anónima recibiría `a` como `25` y `b` como `100`? , entonces resultaría como `-75`, y **como obteniendo** un `-75`, **la función sabe que** *25 es menor que 100* ?

3) Y porque `a-b` los ordena **de menor a mayor**, y porque `b-a` **de mayor a menor**?

```js
var array = ["25","100","40","200"];

array.sort(function(a,b){
  
  return a-b;
  
});

document.write(array);
```

Answer (score 1):

La función que se le pasa al método `sort` es una `compareFunction`en este caso un `callback` pero podría ser tranquilamente el nombre de una función creada previamente y no habría problemas.

> Se supone que son strings, como los suma, los convierte a numero
>   primeramente?

Quiero iniciar diciendo que **Javascript no es un lenguaje tipado** , además en la documentación *(dejaré en link como referencias)*  dice que cuando una función de comparación es usada, los números se ordenan correctamente ya sean números o **`strings numéricos`** *como es este ejemplo*

Qué pasa si trato de ordenar el siguiente arreglo de `String` , no lo ordenará porque  no son datos numéricos ni tampoco string numéricos, la resta de `string` produce un `NaaN`

```js
var array = ["Hola","Mundo","Ayer"];
array.sort(function(a,b){
  return a-b;
});
console.log(array);
```

Para estos casos es mejor comparar directamente los String empleando métodos como `localeCompare`

```js
var array = ["Hola","Mundo","Ayer"];
array.sort(function(a,b){
  return a.localeCompare(b);
});
console.log(array);
```

> Un array con dos elementos "25" y "100" ,la función anónima recibiría a como 25 y b como 100? , entonces resultaría como -75, y como obteniendo un -75, la función sabe que 25 es menor que 100 ?

La documentación da unas reglas básicas para este comportamiento.

- Si `compareFunction(a, b)` es menor que 0, se sitúa a en un indice menor que b. Es decir, a viene primero.
- Si `compareFunction(a, b)`  retorna 0, se deja a y b sin cambios entre ellos, pero ordenados con respecto a todos los elementos diferentes. Nota: el estandar ECMAscript no garantiza este comportamiento, por esto no todos los navegadores (p.ej.  Mozilla en versiones que datan hasta el 2003) respetan esto.
- Si `compareFunction(a, b)` es mayor que 0, se sitúa b en un indice menor que a.

**`Para su pregunta daría menor que 0 es decir  -75 por lo tanto 25 va antes de 100`**

> Y porque a-b los ordena de menor a mayor, y porque b-a de mayor a menor?

Está relacionado con el segundo punto y las especificaciones del método `compareFunction` , el orden de los valores `a` y `b` afectará el resultado para determinar que elementos van antes.

> Como información adicional , si no se le especifica la función de
>   comparación el ordenamiento se hará dependiendo del valor [Unicode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types#Unicode)
>   de cada valor.

[Referencia](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/sort)