# ¿Cómo funciona realmente sort?

Tags: javascript

El método `sort()` de ***Javascript***, ordena un array según la función comparativa que se aplique, y si no se pasa una función comparativa se ordena de una manera extraña ( *que no entiendo y también me gustaría saber*), sé realizarlo , pero no como funciona realmente, ya que no me gusta realizar las cosas *como un robot*, **sino que entender lo que hago.**

***Por ejemplo si quiero ordenar un array de menor a mayor hago esto:***

```js
var an = [34,99,2,4,77,109];
var c = an.sort((a,b) => {
    return a - b;
});
console.log(c);
```

Pero, **que es** `a` y `b` ?

y **además**, por qué esto me devuelve el `array` **ordenado de mayor a menor:** ?

```js
var array = [1,2,3,4,5,6];

var c = array.sort(() => Math.random() + array.length);
console.log(c);
```

Comment: Encontré [esta respuesta en SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37245185) que muestra la implementación de `sort` para _V8, el motor JavaScript de Chrome_. Cada navegador lo hace de diferente manera.

Comment: Parte de esta pregunta ya la [formulaste anteriormente](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/81356/cómo-funciona-el-método-sort-con-functiona-breturn-a-b-como-argumento/81363#81363)

Answer (score 1):

Las variables `a` y `b` son los elementos que se comparan en cada iteración. Se puede hacer una lista de todas las comparaciones que se hacen.

```js
var salida=""
var an = [34,99,2,4,77,109];
var c = an.sort((a,b) => {
    salida+="(a: "+a+", b: "+b+", a-b: "+(a-b)+")\n"
    return a - b;
});
console.log(salida)
```

La segunda función, en realidad no ordena al array, sino que es equivalente a hacer `array.reverse()`, es decir, lo lee para atrás.

Esto sucede porque el resultado de `Math.random() + array.length` siempre es mayor a 0, y entonces, hace un recorrido en el que siempre intercambia los valores.

El siguiente código, va mostrando cómo queda el `array` en cada momento.

```js
var array = [5,4,8,9];

var c = array.sort(function(){
  console.log(array+"")
  return Math.random() + array.length
})
console.log(c+"");
```

Answer (score 0):

Cada explorador puede implementar cualquier algoritmo de ordenamiento, sin embargo nosotros podemos indicarle al ordenamiento que elemento es mayor o menor o incluso si son el mismo elemento por medio de una función que se le pasa como parametro a la función sort.

Esta función recibe dos parametros, los cuales son los elementos a comparar y debe de regresar un numero que será interpretado de la siguiente forma:

- 0: Los elementos comparados son el mismo
- Negativo: El primer elemento tiene que estar a la izquierda del segundo
- Positivo: El primer elemento tiene que estar a la derecha del segundo

Por eso la mayoría usa una resta para retornar un valor por ejemplo:

```
// A  , B
  [500,100]

A = 500
B = 100
resta = B - A; //(100 - 500)
//Resta es negativo (-400) A tiene que ir primero que B: [500,100]
```

El mismo ejemplo pero para un ordenamiento ascendente

```
//A , B
[500,100]
A = 500
B = 100
resta = A - B; //(500 - 100)
//Resta es positivo (400) B tiene que ir primero que A: [100,500]
```

Aquí emulare el metodo de ordenamiento por inserción

```js
Array.prototype.ordena = miOrdena;

var arreglo = [-2,-5,6,8,3];

function miOrdena(comparar){
  var numero1;
  var numero2;
  var index1;
  var index2;  
  var resultado;
  var funcComparar;
  var cambio;
  
  funcComparar = comparar;
  
  for(var i=0; i<this.length; i++){    
    index1 = i;
    index2 = i - 1;   
    
    do{
      console.log("-------------------------");
      cambio = false;
      if(index2 >= 0)
      {
        numero1 = this[index1];
        numero2 = this[index2];
        console.log("Comparando " + numero1 + " vs ", numero2);
        resultado = funcComparar(numero1, numero2);      
        console.log("Resultado de la comparacion : ", resultado);
        if(resultado > 0)      {
          console.log("Resultado > 0, Se cambia el orden");
          this[index2] = numero1;
          this[index1] = numero2;
          cambio = true;
        }
        else
          console.log("Resultado <= 0, Orden se mantiene ");
        index1--;
        index2--;        
      }
      console.log(this);
    }while(cambio);
  }      
}

function asc(numero1, numero2){
  return numero2 - numero1; 
}

arreglo.ordena(asc);
console.log(arreglo);
```

En el siguiente ejemplo se emula la funcion default de ordenamiento, el cual obtiene el valor unicode de cada elemento para su comparación

```js
Array.prototype.ordena = miOrdena;

var arreglo = [-2,-5,6,8,3];

function miOrdena(comparar){
  var numero1;
  var numero2;
  var index1;
  var index2;  
  var resultado;
  var funcComparar;
  var cambio;
  
  if(!comparar)
    funcComparar = comparaDefault;
  else
    funcComparar = miOrdena;
  
  for(var i=0; i<this.length; i++){    
    index1 = i;
    index2 = i - 1;   
    
    do{
      console.log("-------------------------");
      cambio = false;
      if(index2 >= 0)
      {
        numero1 = this[index1];
        numero2 = this[index2];
        console.log("Comparando " + numero1 + " vs ", numero2);
        resultado = funcComparar(numero1, numero2);      
        console.log("Resultado de la comparacion : ", resultado);
        if(resultado > 0)      {
          console.log("Resultado > 0, Se cambia el orden");
          this[index2] = numero1;
          this[index1] = numero2;
          cambio = true;
        }
        else
          console.log("Resultado <= 0, Orden se mantiene ");
        index1--;
        index2--;        
      }
      console.log(this);
    }while(cambio);
  }      
}
function comparaDefault(valor1, valor2){
  var str1 = valor1.toString();
  var str2 = valor2.toString();
  var result;
  var code1;
  var code2;
  
  for(var i=0; i<str1.length;i++){
    code1 = str1.charCodeAt(i);
    code2 = str2.charCodeAt(i);
    result = code2-code1;
    console.log("char de str1: '"+str1[i]+"' (code "+ code1 +") \n" 
    +"char de str2: '"+str2[i]+"' (code "+ code2 +")\n"
    +code1 + " - " + code2 + "=" + result);
    if(result == 0){
      console.log("Mismo caracter");
    }
    else 
      return result;
  }
}


arreglo.ordena();
console.log(arreglo);
```